# How to check source code libraries of openJDK?

Tags: java, java-17

I have installed openJDK 17. Then I have unzipped file lib/src.zip. There are a lot of directories and I cannot find packages like java.lang or java.util. How can I find it?

I have tried to use search and so on. Also, I know that I can use IntelJ or Eclipse for it, but I want to do it without IDEs

Comment: On linux you can use the "find" program.

Comment: I would add into here the "tree", "grep" utilities (linux macos)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The top-level directories of Java's `src.zip` are - since Java 9 - the modules. The package `java.lang` is part of the module `java.base`. You can find the sources of classes in `java.lang` in `java.base/java/lang` inside the zip.

For module names, the directory name is the full module name, while for package names, each `.` separated part represents a nested directory (`java.lang` -> `java/lang`, `java.lang.annotation` -> `java/lang/annotation`, etc.). For example, the sources of `java.lang.String` are in the file `java.base/java/lang/String.java`

Depending on what your end goal is, it might make more sense to clone the GitHub repository of OpenJDK:

- https://github.com/openjdk/jdk17u for current state of Java 17
- https://github.com/openjdk/jdk for mainline development of Java